# List of list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list called 'mylist'. It contains 2 items. Each of these items is a list of data frame(s). The first item of the list is a list of 1 data frame and the second item is the list of 2 data frames like so :-

```
str(mylist1)
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
  ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 21000 23400 26800
  ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14"
> str(mylist2)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
  ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 21000 23400 26800
  ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14"
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe1" "Peter Gynn1" "Jolie Hope1"
  ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 20000 25000 30000
  ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2011-11-01" "2009-03-25" "2008-03-14"
> str(mylist)
List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
  .. ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 21000 23400 26800
  .. ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
  .. ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 21000 23400 26800
  .. ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe1" "Peter Gynn1" "Jolie Hope1"
  .. ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 20000 25000 30000
  .. ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2011-11-01" "2009-03-25" "2008-03-14"
```

The list itself looks like so :-

```
mylist1
[[1]]
    employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14

> mylist2
[[1]]
    employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14

[[2]]
     employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe1  20000 2011-11-01
2 Peter Gynn1  25000 2009-03-25
3 Jolie Hope1  30000 2008-03-14

> mylist
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
    employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
    employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14

[[2]][[2]]
     employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe1  20000 2011-11-01
2 Peter Gynn1  25000 2009-03-25
3 Jolie Hope1  30000 2008-03-14
```

If I were to assign the list 'mylist' to a variable like so :-

```
testvar <- mylist
```

The command :-

str(testvar)

gives the following output correctly.

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
  .. ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 21000 23400 26800
  .. ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
  .. ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 21000 23400 26800
  .. ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ employee : chr [1:3] "John Doe1" "Peter Gynn1" "Jolie Hope1"
  .. ..$ salary   : num [1:3] 20000 25000 30000
  .. ..$ startdate: Date[1:3], format: "2011-11-01" "2009-03-25" "2008-03-14"
```

But the following command gives an error :-

```
str(get(paste0("testvar", "[[1]]")))
```

Error

```
Error in get(paste0("testvar", "[[1]]")) : 
  object 'testvar[[1]]' not found
```

Why does the above command not find the testvar object which effectively is the list 'mylist'. I want to be able to get the structure (or even class) of the first item of the list 'mylist'. I need to do it programmatically and cannot hard code it.

Any suggestions please?

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` or `mget` returns only the object/objects that are created in the global environment.  `"testvar"` is an object that is created with values while "testvar[[1]]" is not an object identifier, it is just one of the elements of the `list` `testvar`.  So, we `get` the value of the object identifier and extract the `list` element with `[[`

```
get("testvar")[[1]]
```

---

It is similar to getting the column of a data.frame

```
data(mtcars)
get("mtcars") # // => works
get("mtcars[[1]]") # // => returns error
```

> Error in get("mtcars[[1]]") : object 'mtcars[[1]]' not found

---

It is not clear why we need to use `get`.  If the intention is to loop over the `mylist`, it can be done with `lapply`

```
lapply(mylist, function(innerlst) yourfun(innerlst))
```

Comment: akrun<- Holy cow! This 'get("testvar")[[1]]' works. Don't fully get it but it works OK. I will also look in to the 'lapply' solution.I am trying to understand the meaning of '"testvar[[1]]" is not an object identifier, it is just one of the elements of the list testvar'. Aren't we trying to do just that - 'get the the elements of the list testvar' by doing 'testvar[[1]]'. Obviously, I am wrong but need some clarifications for my better understanding please!

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal It is checking for an identifier name created in the global environment i.e. `testvar[[1]]` which is not created, but you have only `testvar`, that is the reason it didn't work

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal. When you do `a <- 1:5` and check `get('a')` it returns the vector.  but there is no object named 'a[1]'.  so `get("a[1]")` returns error

Comment: akrun<- Good-O, mate! Got it now! Thanks a zillion!

Comment: arkun <- is there a way to store the number of rows for the data frames in the 2 list items in another list (with obviously 2 items)? The first item of this new list should values of (3, -1) and the second (3, 3) because there is only 1 df in in the first list item 2 in the second. -1 is supposed to represent absence of the data frame. The number of items in the new list shall be the maximum number of data frames in the original list - 2 in this example.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal The `-1` is not clear to me.  If you want to find the number of elements of the `list` use `lengths(mylist1)` `lengths(mylist2)` and the number of rows would be `sapply(mylist1, nrow)`

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Does 3 represents the total number of data.frames?  I didn't get the logic for calcuation

Comment: Sorry, that was not what I meant. As you know that these 2 list items contain 1 and 2 df resp. The max. number of df's in this list is 2. I want to store row count of these df in each of the list items as a 2 value pair = for first item as (3, -1) and for the second as (3, 3). The reason is that as the first list item only has 1 df, the second value is missing and I am specifying it as -1. I will try out the sapply solution to see if it works but just want to know  if what I would like is feasible or not. Thanks.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal not clear about the logic  Perhaps this helps `mylist <- list(list(iris), replicate(2, mtcars, simplify = FALSE))
;out <- sapply(mylist, function(x) {x1 <- sapply(x, is.data.frame);sum(x1) }); cbind(sum(out), ifelse(out == max(out), max(out), out - max(out)))`

Comment: akrun <- I don't quite get your code at a glance. I am working on it and will let you know!